# How to share the variable between two threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a loop that doing this:

```
            WorkTask wt = new WorkTask();
            wt.count = count;
            Thread a = new Thread(wt);
            a.start();
```

When the workTask is run, the count will wt++ , 
but the WorkTask doesn't seems change the count number, and between the thread, the variable can't share within two thread, what did I wrote wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code for `WorkThread` it's hard to pin down the problem, but most likely you are missing synchronization between the two threads.

Whenever you start a thread, there are no guarantees on whether the original thread or the newly created thread runs first, or how they are scheduled.  The JVM/operating system could choose to run the original thread to completion and then start running the newly created thread, run the newly created thread to completion and then switch back to the original thread, or anything in between.

In order to control how the threads run, you have to synchronize them explicitly.  There are several ways to control the interaction between threads - certainly too much to describe in a single answer.  I would recommend [the concurrency trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) of the Java tutorials for a broad overview, but in your specific case the synchronization mechanisms to get you started will probably be [Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) and the synchronized keyword (one specific use of this keyword is described in [the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Make the count variable static (it looks like each thread has its own version of the variable right now) and use a mutex to make it thread safe (ie use the synchronized instruction)

Answer (score 1):

From your description I came up with the following to demonstrate what I perceived as your issue. This code, should output 42.  But it outputs 41.

```
public class Test {
static class WorkTask implements Runnable {
    static int count;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;
    }
}
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    WorkTask wt = new WorkTask(); 
    wt.count = 41; 
    Thread a = new Thread(wt); 
    a.start();
    System.out.println(wt.count);
}
}
```

The problem is due to the print statement running before thread had a chance to start.

To cause the current thread ( the thread that is going to read variable count ) to wait until the thread finishes, add the following after starting thre thread.

```
a.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wishing to get a result back from a thread, I would recommend you to use Callable 
interface and an ExecutorSercive to submit it. e.g:

```
    Future future = Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit
    (new Callable<Interger>()
    {
        int count = 1000;

        @Override public Integer call() throws Exception
        {
            //here goes the operations you want to be executed concurrently.
            return count + 1;   //Or whatever the result is.
        }
    }

    //Here goes the operations you need before the other thread is done.

    System.out.println(future.get());    //Here you will retrieve the result from
    //the other thread. if the result is not ready yet, the main thread 
    //(current thread) will wait for it to finish.
```

this way you don't have to deal with the synchronization problems and etc.
you can see further about this in Java documentations:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html